# Vertex AI "annotation label deduped error"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

I have uploaded a csv for image classification. I have checked the csv for any errors or duplicate values. But when I import the csv, i get the error that annotation is deduped and only a few images out of all the images are getting imported.

i labelled the images without whitespaces

What could be the possible cause for this?